# Django: "request" does not contain the 'method' (POST/GET)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I've created a [seemingly] straightforward form for customers, however, after the user submits the form, when i try to check the returning request m- I'm getting :

**Exception Type:
AttributeError
Exception Value:
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'method'**

when i checked I saw that the request objects contains only the data submitted in the form, and doesn't include the "method" attribute

this is the function that is used by the form:

```
def institutionapply(request):
    print(request)
    print("request: ",request)
    a=get_ip(request)
    print (a)
    country=get_country(request)
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = institutionapply(request.POST)
        print ("form in post clause:",form)
        #print ("duration output:",form.duration)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print ("print form is valid")
            print (form.cleaned_data['title'])
            print (form.cleaned_data['country'])

            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
            #return redirect(name='home')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        data = {'title': '', 'first': '', 'last':'', 'country':'','internationalprefix':'','phone':'','email':'','institutionname':'','institutionurl':'',}
        form = institutionform(data)
    return render(request,'app/intitutionapply.html', {'form': form})
```

any ideas why the "method" object is nowhere to be found?

EDIT : url configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^InstitutionApply$', views.institutionapply, name='institutionapply'),
    url(r'^contact$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

from the html template , the form declaration is:

**the functions from views.py**

```
def get_country(request):
    a=get_ip(request)
    country='United States'
    g = GeoIP2(path='D:/newTelumis/newTelumis/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
    return country



def  get_ip(request):
    try:
        x_forward= request.META.get("HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR")
        if x_forward:
            ip=x_forward.split(",")[0]
        else:
            ip=request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
    except:
        ip=""
    return ip
```

Comment: What do the print statements show? And is this function called directly from a URL?

Comment: Do `get_ip` or `get_country` manipulate the request?

Comment: @DanielRoseman 

 the print is showing:

request:  <QueryDict: {'first': [''], 'title': ['34345'], 'email': [''], 'institutionurl': [''], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['8OrIkQAgZoCYJxzvcL1xHMhL7a0rmaUQ'], 'country': [''], 'phone': [''], 'last': [''], 'internationalprefix': [''], 'institutionname': ['']}>

the form is posting to the same url (if this is what you meant)

Comment: So somehow this function is only receiving `request.POST`, not the actual request. Please show the url configuration for this view.

Comment: @Sayse the functions do not manipulate the request

function are trying to read info from the request

def get_country(request):
    a=get_ip(request)
    country='United States'
    #print (a)
    g = GeoIP2(path='D:/newTelumis/newTelumis/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
    return country

and 

def  get_ip(request):
    try:
        x_forward= request.META.get("HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR")
        if x_forward:
            ip=x_forward.split(",")[0]
        else:
            ip=request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
    except:
        ip=""
    return ip

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38845737/edit) button to update your question.

Comment: i've edited the question and added the info requested

Comment: Does the admin work? Do you have any custom middleware classes?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  admin works perfectly. no custom classes whatsoever.

Comment: Is there anything else called request in your application? Global variables?.. Essentially, something is making request something that it shouldn't be. That something isn't shown in the code above, you should try to create an [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def institutionapply(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        form = institutionapply(request.POST)
```

Replace `institutionapply` with `institutionform`.

Comment: Well spotted. The problem is that the view was being called recursively.